# How to add new user role to jhipster(4.0.3) application

Tags: angular, jhipster

I've created **angular 2** application using **Jhipster**. i want use new user role like **ROLE_MANAGER** in my application to route him to different view after logging in, what are all the files i need to change in back-end and in UI can anyone help me.

i tried changing following files not succeded, new role is not adding in database table.

```
src\main\java\com\mycompany\myapp\security\AuthoritiesConstants.java
src\main\resources\config\liquibase\authorities.csv
src\main\resources\config\liquibase\users_authorities.csv
```

if anyone done this before please explain how to route each user to different views.

Comment: there are 2 questions here...if you change those files after migration is done, its normal there are no changes. delete the /target folder in dev mode or use the clean task for mvn/gradle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version, your problem may solved by performing the following changes to your generated angular application

### change the login service (login.service.ts) to return account instead of token

in

```
login (credentials, callback?) {
    let cb = callback || function() {};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.authServerProvider.login(credentials).subscribe(data => {
            this.principal.identity(true).then(account => {
                // After the login the language will be changed to
                // the language selected by the user during his registration
                if (account !== null) {
                    this.languageService.changeLanguage(account.langKey);
                }
                resolve(data);
            });
            return cb();
        }, err => {
            this.logout();
            reject(err);
            return cb(err);
        });
    });
}
```

change `resolve(data)` to `resolve(account)`

### catch the account in login.component.ts

in the function login, add account to then() like this

```
login () {
    this.loginService.login({
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
        rememberMe: this.rememberMe
    }).then((account: Account) => {
        this.authenticationError = false;
        this.activeModal.dismiss('login success');
        if (this.router.url === '/register' || this.router.url === '/activate' ||
            this.router.url === '/finishReset' || this.router.url === '/requestReset') {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
        }

        this.eventManager.broadcast({
            name: 'authenticationSuccess',
            content: 'Sending Authentication Success'
        });

        // // previousState was set in the authExpiredInterceptor before being redirected to login modal.
        // // since login is succesful, go to stored previousState and clear previousState
        let previousState = this.stateStorageService.getPreviousState();
        //**CHANGED** check if we have are a manager
        let isManager = account.authorities.indexOf("ROLE_MANAGER") > -1;
        if(isManager) { 
            this.stateStorageService.resetPreviousState();
            this.router.navigate(['your-manager-specific-state']);
        } 
        else if (previousState) {
            this.stateStorageService.resetPreviousState();
            this.router.navigate([previousState.name], { queryParams:  previousState.params });
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        this.authenticationError = true;
    });
}
```

This will check the account for having the ROLE_MANAGER role being present, and overrides the default behavior, which redirects the user to the previous state.