# Adding role jhipster 4.0.1 , angular2 , typescript

Tags: jhipster

I'm creating application using JHipster 4.0.1 with angular 2 , typescript and MongoDb and I'm trying to add new roles. 
I added new constants to security/AuthoritiesConstants but what is the others steps.

Is anybody knows how to add my new role ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the steps needed are already done by the thread author of [How to add new user role to jhipster(4.0.3) application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298154/how-to-add-new-user-role-to-jhipster4-0-3-application)

The roles are stored in database and have to be provisioned before. In addition, you must add the new roles in client, to being able to apply the new roles to users in user management.

you can find them in "/src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-dialog.component.ts" in

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.authorities = ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']; //add more roles here
    this.languageHelper.getAll().then((languages) => {
        this.languages = languages;
    });
    this.jhiLanguageService.setLocations(['user-management']);
}
```

Comment: After doing all that and adding 'ROLE_MANAGER' into /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/repository/AuthorityRepository.java                 . I think because the role is not added into the database

Comment: you have to add them into src/main/resources/config/liquibase/authorities.csv and afterwards ./mvnw clean / ./gradlew clean

Comment: I don't have this file i don't know why i add manually ROLE_MANAGER into table jhi_authority using mongo shell it works good . Thanks

Comment: All roles are added but can not login and acces to home page . c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Enter:

Comment: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Feb 20 14:39:29 CET 2017, principal=ala, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Bad credentials}]]
2017-02-20 14:39:29.062 DEBUG 17004 --- [ XNIO-2 task-10] c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null

Comment: 2017-02-20 14:39:29.062 DEBUG 17004 --- [ XNIO-2 task-10] c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exit: com.mycompany.myapp.web.rest.UserJWTController.authorize() with result = <401 Unauthorized,{AuthenticationException=Bad credentials},{}>
 c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Feb 20 14:39:29 CET 2017, principal=ala, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE,

Comment: data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Bad credentials}]]
2017-02-20 14:39:29.062 DEBUG 17004 --- [ XNIO-2 task-10] c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2017-02-20 14:39:29.062 DEBUG 17004 --- [ XNIO-2 task-10] c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exit: com.mycompany.myapp.web.rest.UserJWTController.authorize() with result = <401 Unauthorized,{AuthenticationException=Bad credentials},{}>

Comment: it looks like a specific issue to your code base now